# Color ComboBox Custom Control designer problem

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics, combobox, user-controls

I have a Custom Control that displays color selections in a drop down and it works good.
I found the performance was poor with multiple controls on the same Form so I changed it to store the Color index in the Items collection.
This works good but the Designer gets populated with a large array of values and this causes empty items in the control.

How do I stop the designer from storing the Items?

Here is the designer code I don't want:

```
Me.cboCWarcColor.Items.AddRange(New Object() 
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
     19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 
     36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
     53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 
     70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 
     87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 
     103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 
     116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 
     129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140}
)
```

Here is the Custom Control code:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class ColorCombo
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Private mSelectedColor As Color = Nothing
    Private Shared myColors As New List(Of Color)
    Private Shared myColorsIndices As New List(Of Object)

    Private Sub ColorCombo_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles Me.DrawItem
        Try
            If e.Index < 0 Or e.Index >= myColors.Count Then
                e.DrawBackground()
                e.DrawFocusRectangle()
                Exit Try
            End If
            ' Get the Color object from the Items list
            Dim aColor As Color = myColors.Item(e.Index) 'myColors.Item(e.Index)

            ' get a square using the bounds height
            Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(4, e.Bounds.Top + 2, CInt(e.Bounds.Height * 1.5), e.Bounds.Height - 4)


            ' call these methods first
            e.DrawBackground()
            e.DrawFocusRectangle()

            Dim textBrush As Brush
            ' change brush color if item is selected
            If e.State = DrawItemState.Selected Then
                textBrush = Brushes.White
            Else
                textBrush = Brushes.Black
            End If

            ' draw a rectangle and fill it
            Dim p As New Pen(aColor)
            Dim br As New SolidBrush(aColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, rect)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rect)

            ' draw a border
            rect.Inflate(1, 1)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect)
            ' draw the Color name
            e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit
            e.Graphics.DrawString(aColor.Name, Me.Font, textBrush, rect.Width + 5, ((e.Bounds.Height - Me.Font.Height) \ 2) + e.Bounds.Top)

            p.Dispose()
            br.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception
            e.DrawBackground()
            e.DrawFocusRectangle()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()
        Try
            Dim aColorName As String
            Me.BeginUpdate()
            Items.Clear()
            SelectedItem = Nothing
            If myColors.Count = 0 Then
                Dim names() As String = System.Enum.GetNames(GetType(System.Drawing.KnownColor))
                For Each aColorName In names
                    If aColorName.StartsWith("Active") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Button") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Window") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Inactive") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("HighlightText") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Control") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Scroll") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Menu") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Gradient") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("App") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Desktop") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("GrayText") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("HotTrack") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Transparent") _
                    Or aColorName.StartsWith("Info") Then
                    Else
                        AddColor(Color.FromName(aColorName))
                    End If
                Next

            Else
                Me.Items.AddRange(myColorsIndices.ToArray)
            End If

        Catch
        Finally
            Me.EndUpdate()
        End Try
        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    End Sub

    Public Function AddColor(clr As Color) As Integer
        myColors.Add(clr)
        Dim idx As Integer = myColors.Count - 1
        myColorsIndices.Add(idx)
        Me.Items.Add(idx)
        Return idx
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a named color if one matches else it returns the passed color
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function GetKnownColor(ByVal c As Color, Optional ByVal tolerance As Double = 0) As Color
        For Each clr As Color In myColors
            If ColorDistance(c, clr) <= tolerance Then
                Return clr
            End If
        Next
        Return c
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns index if one matches
    ''' </summary>
    Public Function ContainsColor(ByVal c As Color) As Integer
        Dim idx As Integer = 0
        For Each clr As Color In myColors
            If c.ToArgb = clr.ToArgb Then
                Return idx
            End If
            idx += 1
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function

    Sub ColorCombo_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SelectedIndexChanged
        If SelectedIndex >= 0 Then
            mSelectedColor = myColors.Item(SelectedIndex)
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Property SelectedColor() As Color
        Get
            'If mSelectedColor.Name = "Transparent" Then
            '    Return Color.Black
            'End If
            Return mSelectedColor
        End Get

        Set(ByVal value As Color)
            Try
                Dim smallestDist As Double = 255
                Dim currentDist As Double = 0
                Dim bestMatch As Integer = 0
                Dim idx As Integer = -1
                For Each c As Color In myColors
                    idx += 1
                    currentDist = ColorDistance(c, value)
                    If currentDist < smallestDist Then
                        smallestDist = currentDist
                        bestMatch = idx
                    End If
                Next
                If Me.Items.Count >= bestMatch Then
                    Me.SelectedIndex = bestMatch
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Debug.Print(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function ColorDistance(ByRef clrA As Color, ByRef clrB As Color) As Double
        Dim r As Long, g As Long, b As Long
        r = CShort(clrA.R) - CShort(clrB.R)
        g = CShort(clrA.G) - CShort(clrB.G)
        b = CShort(clrA.B) - CShort(clrB.B)
        Return Math.Sqrt(r * r + g * g + b * b)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding the Color selection to the ComboBox.Items collection, the Form Designer serializes this this collection, adding all items to the Form.Designer.vb file. This also happens when you add Items a ComboBox using the Properties pane in the Designer: same *effect*.

You can instead set the DataSource of the ComboBox: it's faster and the object you add are not serialized. I also suggest not to add these values in the Control Constructor, but in the [OnHandleCreated()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.onhandlecreated) override: the values are loaded only when the Control Handle is created, at run-time, so you don't load (not so useful) collections of items in the designer.
Since the handle can be recreated at run-time, more than once, there's a check for that (to avoid building the collection more than once).

Here, I'm using the [ColorConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.colorconverter)'s [GetStandardValues()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.getstandardvalues) method to build a collection of known colors, excluding from the enumeration colors that have the [IsSystemColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.issystemcolor) property set.
The collection is store in an array of Color objects, here named **`supportedColors`**.

You can also filter the collection returned by [[Enum].GetValues()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues) to get the same result, e.g.:

```
Dim colors As Color() = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(KnownColor)).OfType(Of KnownColor)().
    Where(Function(kc) kc > 26 AndAlso kc < 168).
    Select(function(kc) Color.FromKnownColor(kc)).ToArray()
```

SystemColors have Indexes < 27 and > 167 (I suggest not to rely on these values).

I've made a few changes to Custom Control:

- When a Control is derived from an existing class, we don't subscribe to the events (e.g., `DrawItem`), we override the methods that rise the events (e.g., [`OnDrawItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.ondrawitem)), then call `base` (`MyBase`) to rise the event (eventually, we can also not do that, if necessary). We are always one step ahead this way.
- The drawing part needed some refactoring:

  - The Item's background actually was drawn 3 times
  - Disposable object should be declared with a `Using` statement, so we don't *forget* to dispose of them: very important when it comes to Graphics objects.
  - Replaced `Graphics.DrawString()` with [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext), to respect the original drawing.
  - Simplified the calculations: it's important to be as fast as possible here.
  - Thus also remove all `Try/Catch` blocks: costly and not really needed (don't use `Try/Catch` blocks when drawing, a few `If` conditions and some constraints - e.g., `Math.Min(Math.Max()`) - are better).
  - Also overridden [OnMeasureItem()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.onmeasureitem) to change the height of the Items, set to `Font.Height + 4` (pretty standard).
  - Other stuff you can see in the source code.

---

I've changed the **`SelectedColor`** custom property to be more *reliable* and to make it work with both [OnSelectedIndexChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.onselectedindexchanged) and [OnSelectionChangeCommitted()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.onselectionchangecommitted).
All Items represent a Color, so you can get the Color selected as, e.g.:

```
Private Sub ColorCombo1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ColorCombo1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    SomeControl.BackColor = DirectCast(ColorCombo1.SelectedItem, Color)
    ' Or
    SomeControl.BackColor = ColorCombo1.SelectedColor
End Sub
```

---

Modified the ComboBox Custom Control:

- Remove what you have in `Public Sub New` and `InitializeComponent()`, it's not needed anymore.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class ColorCombo
    Inherits ComboBox

    Private mSelectedColor As Color = Color.Empty
    Private supportedColors As Color() = Nothing

    Public Sub New()
        DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable
        FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
        FormattingEnabled = False
        ' Set these just to show that the background color is important here
        ForeColor = Color.White
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(32, 32, 32)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
        If DesignMode OrElse Me.Items.Count > 0 Then Return

        supportedColors = New ColorConverter().GetStandardValues().OfType(Of Color)().
            Where(Function(c) Not c.IsSystemColor).ToArray()

        ' Preserves a previous selection if any
        Dim tmpCurrentColor = mSelectedColor
        Me.DisplayMember = "Name"
        Me.DataSource = supportedColors
        If Not tmpCurrentColor.Equals(Color.Empty) Then
            mSelectedColor = tmpCurrentColor
            SelectedColor = mSelectedColor
        End If
    End Sub

    Private flags As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        e.DrawBackground()
        If e.Index < 0 Then Return

        Dim itemColor = supportedColors(e.Index)
        Dim colorRect = New Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + 1, e.Bounds.Y + 1, e.Bounds.Height - 2, e.Bounds.Height - 2)

        Using colorBrush As New SolidBrush(itemColor)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(colorBrush, colorRect)

            Dim textRect = New Rectangle(New Point(colorRect.Right + 6, e.Bounds.Y), e.Bounds.Size)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, itemColor.Name, e.Font, textRect, e.ForeColor, Color.Transparent, flags)
        End Using

        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
        MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnMeasureItem(e As MeasureItemEventArgs)
        e.ItemHeight = Font.Height + 4
        MyBase.OnMeasureItem(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(e As EventArgs)
        If SelectedIndex >= 0 Then mSelectedColor = supportedColors(SelectedIndex)
        MyBase.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e As EventArgs)
        mSelectedColor = supportedColors(SelectedIndex)
        MyBase.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e)
    End Sub

    Public Property SelectedColor As Color
        Get
            Return mSelectedColor
        End Get
        Set
            mSelectedColor = Value
            If Not IsHandleCreated Then Return

            If mSelectedColor.IsKnownColor Then
                SelectedItem = mSelectedColor
            Else
                If supportedColors Is Nothing Then Return
                Dim smallestDist As Double = 255
                Dim currentDist As Double = 0
                Dim bestMatch As Integer = 0
                Dim idx As Integer = -1

                For Each c As Color In supportedColors
                    idx += 1
                    currentDist = ColorDistance(c, Value)
                    If currentDist < smallestDist Then
                        smallestDist = currentDist
                        bestMatch = idx
                    End If
                Next
                If supportedColors.Count >= bestMatch Then
                    mSelectedColor = supportedColors(bestMatch)
                    SelectedItem = mSelectedColor
                End If
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Function ColorDistance(clrA As Color, clrB As Color) As Double
        Dim r As Integer = CInt(clrA.R) - clrB.R
        Dim g As Integer = CInt(clrA.G) - clrB.G
        Dim b As Integer = CInt(clrA.B) - clrB.B
        Return Math.Sqrt(r * r + g * g + b * b)
    End Function

    Public Function GetKnownColor(c As Color, Optional ByVal tolerance As Double = 0) As Color
        For Each clr As Color In supportedColors
            If ColorDistance(c, clr) <= tolerance Then Return clr
        Next
        Return c
    End Function

    Public Function ContainsColor(c As Color) As Integer
        Dim idx As Integer = 0
        For Each clr As Color In Me.Items
            If c.ToArgb = clr.ToArgb Then Return idx
            idx += 1
        Next
        Return -1
    End Function
End Class
```

This is how it works:

[image: Color ComboBox Custom Control]